# Excel VBA: Deleting Entire Row in two spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

The two spreadsheets are essentially copies of each other, except one spreadsheet has a few extra columns of information at the end. Each row contains columns of information for one product, so having consistency is very important. I'm using a worksheet change macro and I made a certain specification so that it wouldn't run if I deleted an entire row like this:

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1000 Then Exit Sub
```

so I then tried this after the If statement and moved the Exit Sub to the end of this line to delete the row in the other spreadsheet (Operational SKU List):

```
Worksheets("Operational SKU List").Cells(Target.EntireRow, Target.Column).Delete
```

I attempted a few variations of this but I always get an issue. I think it might have something to do with the fact that the row is already deleted, so I can't access the "Target" information, but I'm not sure what else to use. The Ultimate Goal is when I delete a row in the spreadsheet that contains the worksheet change macro, that same row will automatically be deleted in the other spreadsheet. The reason why I needed this was because when I deleted a row in the first spreadsheet, and then uploaded the new information to the second spreadsheet, my data would not align anymore because the extra columns to the right were not effected in the other spreadsheet. If I have the row deleted in both at the same time, I won't run into this problem

Thanks.

Comment: Could you include a hidden column in your reactive sheet like this =MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)
to flag records with no match on sheet2, then delete records with a non-numeric value?

Comment: Maybe..., but I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly

Comment: Hang on, the two sheets are identical except the sheet that you are doing work on has some extra columns?

Why not directly reference the cell values?
eg. sheet2 cell A1 has formula =Sheet1!A1, then fill down and fill accross for the relevant columns so any changes are instant and automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try - put the below code in your 1st worksheet code module, and adjust worksheet argument to your 2nd sheet where commented

1st worksheet is where you are deleting rows - 2nd worksheet is where you are epxecting for rows deleting to be mirrored from 1st sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim deletedRowsAddress As String
    Dim deletedRow

    If Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Then

        For Each deletedRow In Target.Rows
            deletedRowsAddress = deletedRowsAddress & "," & deletedRow.row & ":" & deletedRow.row
        Next
        deletedRowsAddress = Right(deletedRowsAddress, Len(deletedRowsAddress) - 1)

        'CHANGE WORKSHEET ARGUEMENT TO YOUR 2d SHEET NAME
        Worksheets("2d sheet").Range(deletedRowsAddress).Delete

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly with the rest of my code as well. I actually ended up using your If statement instead of my If that checks if cells are > 1000